# How to mprotect the data section?

Tags: c, memory, mprotect

I want to mprotect the data section. The following program will not run correctly. I understand the first argument of `mprotect()` should be aligned. But how to get an aligned memory address for the data section?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char s[] = "Hello World!";

int main() {
    if(mprotect(s, strlen(s) + 1, PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
        perror("mprotect()");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
$ ./mprotect_prog
mprotect(): Invalid argument
```

EDIT: I use the following code to get the page size.

```
{
    builtin printf %s '#define PAGESIZE '
    getconf PAGESIZE
} > pagesize.h
```

Then the C code is changed to the following.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pagesize.h"

char s[] __attribute__((aligned(PAGESIZE))) = "Hello World!";

int main() {
    if(mprotect(s, strlen(s) + 1, PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
        perror("mprotect()");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then, I get a segmentation fault. Can anybody reproduce this error? What is wrong with it?

```
$ ./mprotect_prog
Segmentation fault
```

EDIT2: I have to add the following line below the 's' line to make sure `s` occupies a whole page on its own. Then, the program works.

```
char r[] __attribute__((aligned(PAGESIZE))) = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: Did you read the man page of [mprotect(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html)? You need page-aligned address, usually obtained from a successful [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Comment: You could also use [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) and [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) on your executable file. See also [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

Comment: You do some arithmetic, perhaps by casting `s` to `uintptr_t`.  The bigger problem is that there may be other stuff on the same page as `s`, which after your `mprotect` won't be readable or writable anymore.  You could try to use permissions `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC` but that may  not be possible on all platforms (writable + executable is usually an unwanted combination).   So usually you want to ensure `s` is on a page all by itself, and the best way to do that is as Basile says to copy it to a page allocated specially for it.

Comment: How to make the data section take a whole page without sharing the page with other sections?

Comment: The data section contains data for `stdout`, and that data needs to be writable

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    builtin printf %s '#define PAGESIZE '
    getconf PAGESIZE
} > pagesize.h
```

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pagesize.h"

char s[] __attribute__((aligned(PAGESIZE))) = "Hello World!";
char r[] __attribute__((aligned(PAGESIZE))) = "Hello World!";

int main() {
    if(mprotect(s, strlen(s) + 1, PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
        perror("mprotect()");
        return 1;
    }
}
```